# NULL entry upon UPDATE

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio

I am trying to create a login using SQL Server 2017 and Visual Studio C# 2019 but it only throws an exception

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'pass', table 'master.dbo.user'; the column does not allow nulls. UPDATE fails.

The password is encrypted so I am decrypting it and placed under the "pass" column instead of using AS

```
CREATE TABLE user 
(
    userID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    uname VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    pass VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO user(uname, pass)
VALUES
('admin', ENCRYPTBYPASSPHRASE('************', 'admin'));
```

C# code:

```
private void btLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        dbase db = new dbase();

        String user = tbUser.Text;
        //String pass = tbPass.Text;
        SqlCommand update =
            new SqlCommand("UPDATE user SET pass = CONVERT(VARCHAR(255), DECRYPTBYPASSPHRASE('************', pass)) WHERE uname = 'admin'", db.GetConnection());

        db.openConn();
        update.ExecuteNonQuery();
        db.closeConn();

        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter();

        SqlCommand sqlcmd = 
            new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM user WHERE uName = '" + user + "'", db.GetConnection());

        sqlcmd.Parameters.Add("@user", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = user;
        //sqlcmd.Parameters.Add("@pass", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = pass;

        adp.SelectCommand = sqlcmd;
        adp.Fill(table);

        /* check if user exists or not */
        if (table.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Hello");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Incorrect Username/Password.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: that's so many kinds of bad idea. passwords should be stored salted and hashed.

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Comment: Are you intentionally using the `master` database? (master.dbo.user) normally you use a user defined database?

Comment: @MitchWheat how do I decrypt a hash? because I searched that you can't decrypt a hash.

Comment: @DaleK yes. because there is a problem in my SQL Server Authentication, i don't know what it is.

Comment: If you are trying to add actual database users via code, there are stored procedures to use to do that? I don't know if accessing the tables directly works?

Comment: @DaleK i'll see what i can do. thank you!

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-user-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: @paoloroxass: 'you can't decrypt a hash': Correct. That's the whole point!

Comment: You are using Entity.  If you are changing the columns in the database or the c# classes you need to refresh the mapping file so the c# classes and database are synchronized.

Comment: @paoloroxass,based on my test, I can not reproduce your problem. It works well for me. However, I have two suggestions. First, I recommend you use table name 'Users'  instead of 'user'. Second, I advise that you place the table in other database instead of in the database 'master'.